# Do intro algorithm (computer science/complexity) questions belong here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I'm starting to learn about algorithms and complexity via [MIT's OpenCourseWare class](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/). Are questions about this class relevant to Math.SE? The [algorithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms) tag is the general topic, but less so.

Related:
[Are algorithm questions acceptable](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248/are-algorithm-questions-acceptable)

Answer (score 11):

If you're asking about the mathematical details (e.g. what is its time complexity/how do you prove it correct/how can it be generalized) then your question will fit in perfectly here.

If you're asking a question about the *implementation* then it should go on [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The best site for questions about computer science is [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). This includes algorithms and complexity as well as other topics in theoretical and applied computer science.

Theoretical computer science, like theoretical physics, relies heavily on mathematics, so [some questions about theoretical computer science are on-topic here on Mathematics.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248/are-algorithm-questions-acceptable), for example the (theoretical) study of algorithms (e.g. correctness, complexity).

Questions about implementing algorithms are on-topic on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Coding is off-topic on Computer Science, even if the questions arise from a course in a computer science curriculum.

Questions about finding the right algorithm for a particular goal are not driven by mathematical considerations and thus off-topic here. If the consideration is a scientific one (e.g. complexity, type of inputs supported, etc.), such questions belong on [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). If the consideration is an industrial one (e.g. maintainability, availability of libraries, etc.), then [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) would be a better fit.

Comment: see also [Hint: Programmers.SE don't do coding help and expect research before asking](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/21680/279150)