# Should some unanswered computer science questions be migrated to CS.SE?

Tags: discussion, migration, questions, computer-science

I know that [some parts of theoretical computer science are on-topic here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100/is-theoretical-computer-science-on-topic). There is now a [Stack Exchange site dedicated to computer science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). While [this does not affect the scope of Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3619/computer-science-se-coming-up), it might affect the fate of borderline questions.

I know that part of the Math.SE community is [adamantly](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3954/computer-science-questions-being-closed-as-off-topic) [against](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3631/overlap-with-new-cs-theory-lite-site) migrating any question to CS.SE. Hence I have refrained from flagging any question that I thought would have a better home on CS.SE (even though I disagree about the on-topic nature of some questions — for example, I think that recursion theory is on-topic here and shouldn't be migrated, but many [algorithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms) questions are off-topic here and would have a better audience on CS.SE).

There are currently [64 unanswered questions in the `computer-science` tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-science), and probably a few more in related tags. **Should some of these questions get a second chance on CS.SE?**

On a related note, are there any old questions that were tolerated here for lack of a better home, but should now be migrated?

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion would be: after at least two weeks unanswered here, if the original poster still wants to get an answer, he/she should post the question in CS.SE (with links going both ways).

Comment: Please don't recommend this.  You are suggesting that the author re-post the same thing on another site (cross-posting).  Cross-posting on multiple StackExchange sites is prohibited by StackExchange rules.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/160917.  So, you're encouraging people to violate site rules.  Instead, the author should flag their post for moderator attention and ask the moderators to migrate it to CS.SE, if that's what the author wants to have happen (but it should be up to the author, not something forced upon them against their wishes).