# Impossible to migrate to Computer Science SE

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration, computer-science

It appears to be impossible to vote to migrate a question to [Computer Science SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com):
[image]

> So I wonder whether
>
> - It should be possible to migrate to cs.SE
> - Computer Science questions should be migrated at all.

I discovered this while reviewing [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220665) question.

Related: [Should some unanswered computer science questions be migrated to CS.SE?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4601). The suggestion here was to cross-post instead of migrating.

Comment: The site [cs.se] is in "beta;" and no migration-paths are opened to beta-sites as a general policy (moderators can still migrate).

Comment: You can always flag for a moderator to migrate or suggest in a comment that the owner of the post post the question there. (If it's off-topic here, they should delete it, though if it's on-topic, they'd probably be fine cross-posting as long as both questions link to their twin)

Comment: @Ethan you recommended a still different site in a comment. Either way, I think it's so rare that there is little need.

Comment: I agree with @quid. There have been only 2 migrations to CS.SE in the last 90 days. The moderators can surely handle that.

Comment: I've rolled back rev. 7 because it is to the detriment of the question for it not to make sense when read from top to bottom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Non-moderators can only vote to migrate questions to a small set of predefined sites. On Math.SE, the set of potential migration targets consists of Physics.SE and Stats.SE (plus meta).

Stack Exchange staff can add migration targets (up to 5, but few sites have that many). As a matter of general policy, beta sites are not added as migration targets.

Moderators can migrate a question to any site. The only constraint is that the question must be less than 60 days old; even moderators cannot migrate other questions. If you see a question that is off-topic on Math but on-topic on CS and less than 60 days old, flag the question and request the question to be migrated.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220665/graph-diameter-approximation is not a good question and should not be migrated. Although [Computer Science SE allows homework questions](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/468/homework-policy), we don't like problem dumps like this, and generally close them as *unclear what you're asking* — we want the asker to tell us what they tried and where they got stuck so that we can help them with the part that caused them trouble.

The boundary between math (on-topic) and theoretical computer science (off-topic) is a [separate issue](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4601/should-some-unanswered-computer-science-questions-be-migrated-to-cs-se).

Comment: Ha. You use "unclear" the same way we use "off-topic".

Comment: @GerryMyerson actually I find it sometimes very reasonable, and vote so myself (I think I first read a very convincing argument for it by Kate Gregory). Only as the "missing context" is basically also an "unclear" I frequently also use this.  But let me stop here, else we get way off-topic.